# How do I half texel offset when not ortho rendering?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

My rendering is bleeding pixels (the dots in red) along the edge of these two perpendicular quads.

I'm using:

- `GL_NEAREST` min/max texture filtering.
- `texture` function on fragment shader.
- A sprite atlas of 1024x1024, with the desired sprite @ (x=320,y=732,width=8,height=8)

`s1 = 320.0f/1024.0f;
s2 = (320.0f+8.0f)/1024.0f;
t1 = 732.0f/1024.0f;
t2 = (732.0f+8.0f)/1024.0f;`

Render #1 (with a dark texture to make it easier to see bleeding):
[image]

Render #2: (with bright texture for counting texels, but the red pixels are still present):
[image]

I understand that OpenGL's `texture` function will sample at the pixel center, but when I try to offset the "S,T" coordinates by half-a-pixel, it (fixes it but) has adverse effects.

For example, the texture coordinates below shrinks the width of the texels along the border of the sprite.

`s1 = (0.5f+320.0f)/1024.0f;
s2 = (0.5f+320.0f+8.0f)/1024.0f;
t1 = (-0.5f+732.0f)/1024.0f;
t2 = (-0.5f+732.0f+8.0f)/1024.0f;`

[image]

I tried a bunch of possible S&T offset combinations (adding 0.5 to both S&T, subtracting from both, adding to T but subtracting from S) and different values, none of it worked. I don't know what I'm missing; I don't think this is a T-junction issue because the bleeding pixel color is coming from the texture (not the background).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only subtracting or adding a half texel offset will never solve the problem since you will always keep the problem on one side.

What you can do is to clamp your texel coordinates in the range x+0.5 and x+width-0.5 which will prevent bleeding on both sides. The code could looks like this:

```
s = clamp(texCoord.x, 320 + 0.5, 320 + 8 - 0.5) / 1024;
t = clamp(texCoord.y, 732 + 0.5, 732 + 8 - 0.5) / 1024;
```

Comment: Interesting. So unless I'm clamping to [0,1] or using ortho rendering, I have to clamp the coordinates in the fragment shader?

Comment: Yes. If you do it before that it won't reassemble a clamp-to-edge but would instead stretch the texture. The only places where something should happen is in the area between [320, 320.5] and [327.5, 328]. Everywhere else on the texture nothing special should be done. The projection (ortho or perspective) does not make any difference at all. Even with ortho-rendering you'd have to do that in the fragment shader.